# Online Advetisement/Banner Management System

Tags: banner

I am developing site for online advertisements where sellers and buyers can come and sell/buy advertisements.

Just need to develop detailed statistics like click counts, from which page clicks are coming (one advertisement can be placed on many pages), from which position (top, right, left ...) click are coming (one advertisement can be placed in different position on single page) etc. I seen that most of the advertisement on popular websites has following format:

http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=3&CampaignID=838&AdvertiserID=50&BannerID=1335&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=1463177307&Keywords=c%23%2c.net%2ccollections%2cdictionary%2chashtable

It has many parameters like ZoneID, CampaignID, AdvertiserID, BannerID, SiteID, RandomNumber, adid, adcrid, obid, obtid and way. I can use one advertisement (adid) in multiple pages. But can't figure out the way to distinguish between from which pages clicks are coming. How can I use such parameters to generate statistics which tell me the page from which clicks are coming?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious as to why you would want to reinvent this wheel?

Comment: This is client requirement :)

Comment: In that case...

I thought most ad servers used the 'zone' for differentiating the click regions?!

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem is that, will this require publisher (website owner) to go to each page and put the code for different zones (page) manually? I need to make this automatic.

Comment: Usually the zone information is inserted when the client (website) request is made to the server based on the rules that they determine. So, when the client puts in their embed request, they specify the zone (once) and that request transfers through to the ad server. This is a client request for embedding so it's not really a constant maintenance issue. The server will generally allow you to preset the zones - with descriptions, etc. - in order to track that as a metric later. The only time that would change is if the zones change.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Can you please elaborate on how zones are inserted automatically? If I am providing one code like: www.mysite.com/serverad.aspx?adid=125 .How zoneId will be inserted automatically? I am using .NET 3.5, SQL Server 2008

Comment: Ad placement is generally decided at the template level and includes the passing of a zone via the embed code. Aside from using sophisticated Javascript DOM traversal your only option is to have the embed call-out pass the zone along. I've not personally seen another way of passing that zone.